# Why is "will" future used in this sentence?

Tags: future-tense

The following sentence, which is found in a grammar test in a textbook for learners of English called *Tourism 2* (OUP), is given by a tour guide as part of her explanation of a schedule:

> As soon as we get to the station, we'll go to the hotel.

The same textbook contains the following as part of its *Grammar Reference* section:

> *will* is not normally used to talk about timetables or planned events. We use *will* when we decide what to do at that particular moment, e.g. to promise or offer to do something, and to make requests.

Why do we use "will" future here, even though this is clearly not a decision being made at that particular moment. It's pre-planned.

Other future forms which are used to talk about arrangements (present continuous, "going to" future) don't seem to work in this sentence. Why not? Is it something to do with the fact that it's part of an independent clause that follows a dependent clause starting with 'as soon as'?

Comment: Where did you get this idea that **will** is not used for set times, itineraries, and timetables?  Just because the simple present is used with regularly occurring phenomena (*The train departs at 3PM sharp*) does not mean that the future cannot be used in reference to something similar. We can say *...we will go straight to the hotel* and *we are going to go straight to the hotel* and *...we are going straight to the hotel*.

Comment: I've added the source for the idea that *will* is not used for set times, itineraries, and timetables, which is a textbook published by Oxford University Press. The idea that it's based on decisions made *now* rather than pre-planned things is common to every grammar I've read. @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: Some explanation for why question this has been downvoted would be appreciated. I rarely post questions here and I'd like to know what the problem is.

Comment: @Kit Johnson:  A statement about one's *intended course of action* upon reaching a destination is not a "timetable", nor is it an "event".

Comment: I don't think this deserves to be down-voted. Don't get too hung up on one down-vote, especially if you have looked over your question and feel that you have addressed any issues raised in the comments. I hope that someone will take the time to write an *actual* answer to explain that the "planned event" guidance for "will" isn't quite right.

Comment: What I have discovered since asking this question is that this textbook, while technically accurate, doesn't make it clear is that the 'rules' it gives are actually *rules of thumb*. They indicate what will be the most-often chosen form, but in reality there is usually a large degree of flexibility regarding which future form can be used. This comes down to idiolect and what the speaker/writer is trying to emphasise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timetable:

> The morning train to Boston **departs** at 10AM.

A planned event (but one that happens to be recurrent and regular):

> The graduation ceremony **takes place** every year on May 22nd, rain or shine.

A planned "one-off" event:

> The concert **is** on the 17th at 7PM.

A promise:

> As soon as we get to the station, we **will go** to the hotel. I know you're very tired and don't want to begin sightseeing immediately.

But that is not to say that the following would be ungrammatical, as their contexts make the choice of tense perfectly valid:

> The morning train to Boston **will depart** at 10AM.  The switching problems have been repaired, so there will be no delay after all.
>
> The graduation ceremony **will take place** on May 22nd, despite the protests.
>
> The concert has been rescheduled and **is going to take place** on the 18th instead.
>
> As soon as we get to the station we **go** to the hotel. We never go directly to a business meeting without freshening up first.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. That you have written "a promise" makes it much clearer to me.